# iPhone - power button intermittent

Tags: ios, iphone

I recently updated my iPhone to iOS 6.1.2 and after the the update the top "power" button will not consistently lock the screen. Sometimes it needs to pressed 5 to 6 times before it will actually lock the phone.

There does not appear to be anything physically wrong with the button. It still has a nice click feel and sound to it.

I know the last update involved a bug fix for bypassing the lock the screen, so I thought others may be having this same issue.

My guess is it would be a software bug, not a hardware issue.

Other than restore the phone any suggestions?

Comment: You can try restarting or even go as far as restoring the phone, but I'd recommend taking it to a Genius Bar. It's very unlikely to be a software issue. At the very least, I can confirm that my Verizon 4S is not experiencing this.

Comment: @Tyler: I have restarted many times, does not seem to help. I do plan on going to the Genius Bar, but it is difficult for me right now to make it there.  Why do you think it is unlikely to be a software issue?

Comment: I agree with @TylerWayne and would be more inclined to think it's a hardware problem and maybe not software - again, though, that is a guess without more details that may be difficult to provide here. iPhone hardware does break - occasionally.

Comment: @bassplayer7 - I am curious what leads you to believe it is a hardware problem and not software bug? I was thinking software since it started happening after a software update.

Comment: If it happened the day of the software update, that might be sufficient evidence to believe it is indeed a software problem. Honestly, there wasn't much that led me to guess that it was hardware (hence why I was very tentative). From what I have seen (mostly on here) these types of problems are often hardware. Also, by the way, if you use iCloud, restores are very easy, and probably wouldn't take you but a couple hours - it's worth a try.

Comment: Same here. After 6.1.2 or 6.1.3 update this became an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually ended up being a hardware issue. I took my iPhone 5 into an apple store and they said they have seen this happen many times. When I pressed on the right side of the button vs. the left side it seemed to work always. Strange coincidence it just started happening after the software update.

Apple immediately replaced my iPhone 5, no fuss.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: I can confirm, as happened on a 3GS with the volume down button, that the click action doesn't imply closing the circuit and vice versa.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/88777/6962